# Prolog print statement does not work as expected

Tags: prolog

I was trying to define a functor and print each individual items of list in Prolog, but Prolog is not printing in correct format.

```
rint(L):-
    write(H).
```

the output is like
`rint([a, s,v ,c]).`
`_L139`
`true.`

This is what I expect to achieve by calling the functor, any help or thought is appreciated, I'm new to Prolog and learning it.

`?- rint([a,b,c,d]).`

`.(a, .(b, .(c, .(d, []))))`

Comment: You need `write_canonical/1` to get the output you show in the last example.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
rint(L) :- write(L).
```

Also if you want `.(a, .(b, .(c, .(d, []))))` and not `[a, b, c, d]` in output, use `display`:

```
rint(L) :- display(L).
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is an error in your rule for `rint`.

Your definition says that `rint(L)` succeeds if `write(H)` succeeds. At that point, the interpreter knows nothing about `H`. So it writes a value it doesn't know, which is why you see the `_L139`, the internal representation of an uninitialised variable.
Having done that, `write(H)` has succeed, *is true*, so `rint(L)` is true. The interpreter tells you that: `true.`

---

To define your own `rint/1` without relying on built-ins such as `display/1`, you would need to do something like

```
rint([]) :-
    write([]).
rint([H|T]) :-
    write('.('),
    write(H),
    write(', '),
    rint(T),
    write(')').
```

If you're trying to display an empty list, just write it. If you're trying to display any other list, write the opening period and parenthesis, write the Head, write the following comma and space, *then call itself for the Tail of the list*, then write the closing parenthesis.